# Adding a '%' sign after each number I get with a map

Tags: javascript, arrays

`data.risk.scatterIndices.currency.map((el: any) => Number((el.percentage * 100).toFixed(3)))`

How can I add a '%' sign after each number I get with this map of numbers?

Now I get numbers like `[93.5, 5.1, 1.5]`.

It's for the UI of a chart in a React app. I need to add '%' after each number this map function gets for me (e.g. `93.5%`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [ 95.8, 90.3, 80.2 ,50];
 data = data.map(num => num + '%');
console.log(data)
```

data = [93.5, 5.1 , 1.5];
data = data.map(num => num + '%');

Comment: {data && data.risk && data.risk.scatterIndices && data.risk.scatterIndices.currency && data.risk.scatterIndices.currency.map((el: any) => Number((el.percentage * 100).toFixed(3))).map(num => num + '%')  || []}

Comment: I have added a snipe above, what are you getting  a number of arry or empty

Answer (score 0):

Post Edited

```js
const App = () => {
  let datas = [20.1258, 25.6565, 45.988]
    
    const List = () => (
    
    datas.map(el => (console.log(`${el.toFixed(3)}%`), <li>{Number(el * 100).toFixed(3)}%</li>))
    )
    
  
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <ul>
    <List />
    </ul>
    </div>
  );
  
};

ReactDOM.render(
      <App />, document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```